# What full featured cross platform GUI toolkit options are there for embedding in an OpenGL app?

Tags: user-interface, opengl, gtk

I'm writing a fullscreen OpenGL app. Within that I'm going to present a big GL render on the background with a bunch of windows in front, some containing more GL stuff and some containing plain GUI stuff. This sucker needs to run on at least Linux and Windows, Mac would also be nice to have.

What I'm looking for here is GUI toolkit options. I'm after a complete mature system with the full array of widgets, layout helpers, widget focus tracking stuff etc.

My naive notion is to embed something like GTK+, pass it the input events for it's parts of the screen and have it render to buffers that I texture onto GL primitives.

Can GTK+ work like this? What other options are there?

Comment: When thinking of a mature GUI toolkit with every stuff you need Qt comes to my mind. Although I don't know if it can do the things you want (therefore it's no answer), I'm by experience pretty sure this is achievable in an easy and intuitive way with Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend that you check out [Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/) and its [OpenGL module](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtopengl.html). It's able to do all of the things you described.

Best regards

Comment: I concur. Qt abstracts away OpenGL window setup very nicely, and its QGLWidget allows you to place an OpenGL window wherever you can place a Qt widget. Plus, Qt has the kind of maturity and depth you're looking for in a toolkit.

Comment: I can see how that lets me put GL into a QT app, but what I really what is to put QT into a GL app. Am I missing something? To be clear I want to float widgets over the GL view. Like this http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq26-openglcanvas.html except that's 3 years old.

Comment: Although old, the examples in your link are still valid(in principle at least). You can embed QWidget derivatives in QGLWidget.

Comment: yeah, after some jiggling I got that example going, is that still reflective of the best way to do it? I mean if you were shown a video of that and asked to recreate it would you use the same basic approach? or has qt moved on from there?